# Change color of navbar interference with parallax code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make the color of the navbar change after scrolling down but when I do it doesn't work. 
In my page I have first the code for the navbar and then a div where inside of it there's a video canvas with a parallax scrolling down effect.

I assumed it's not working because there might be some interference between the navbar and the parallax code. That's because when I tried to remove the parallax code it was working properly.

The [fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/GqBGRhbUev) of my code with the parallax effect. If you remove the parallax part it works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery is perfectly fine. The reason it works when you remove the parallax is actually due to removal of `overflow` properties from the `.parallax` class in your CSS. Since you have a fixed navbar, this is creating the interference you were mentioning.

```
.parallax {
  perspective: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden; //remove
  overflow-y: auto; //remove
  width: 100%;
}
```

Remove the overflow properties and it should work fine.

Comment: It does work, but now it creates a space on the right: http://imgur.com/a/lSpml and i don't want that.

Comment: Well in that case, you can keep the `overflow` properties(changing both to `overflow: hidden`) and you need to increase the height of the `.parallax` to say `height: 200vh`;

Comment: Still not working. Tried with different values of the height but it hides the content block after the video.